# New to Prolog - procedure `temp(A)' does not exist Reachable from: weather(A) go

Tags: prolog

I've typed out code from a textbook and don't understand where the error lies. It seems to be at weather(Weather),

The error is:

procedure `temp(A)' does not exist
Reachable from:
weather(A)
go

```
/* Weather knowledge base */
weather(good):- 
    temp(high), 
    humidity(dry), 
    sky(sunny).
weather(bad):- 
    (humidity(wet);
    temp(low);
    sky(cloudy)).
/* interface */

go:- 
    write('Is the temperature high or low? '), 
    read(Temp), nl, 
    write('Is the sky sunny or cloudy? '), 
    read(Sky), nl, 
    write('Is the humidity dry or wet? '), 
    read(Humidity), nl, 
    assert(temp(Temp)),
    assert(sky(Sky)),
    assert(humidity(Humidity)),
    weather(Weather),
    write('The weather is '), write(Weather),
    retractall(temp( __ )),
    retractall(sky( __ ) ),
    retractall(humidity( _) ).
```

Comment: what prolog are you using, how are you loading and running the program? I copied your code to a file, loaded it, ran `?- go.`, answered the questions, got an answer that the weather is bad (the weather is quite OK so that was wrong). But I do not see the error that you report. Please update your question to make it reproducible.

Comment: @User9213 The OP seems to be using a new version of SWI-Prolog or its online version at https://swish.swi-prolog.org/ where you can easily reproduce the error message and the singleton warning. What Prolog are *you* using? It makes little sense to say that it works for you if you don't specify *how* it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SWI-Prolog, you should declare `temp/1`, `humidity/1`, and `sky/1` as dynamic, by inserting these three lines in your code.

```
:- dynamic temp/1.
:- dynamic humidity/1.
:- dynamic sky/1.
```

Moreover, if your run your program you get a warning: `Singleton-marked variable appears more than once: __`.
You should replace `__` with `_` in your code to avoid this.

Comment: I do not get any problems with the code as it is in the question, I don't need to declare anything dynamic. It works without this fix. I also have no idea how to reproduce the error from the question.

Comment: I used this website to run the code: https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/bGHbKQgv.pl